# Why does strlen() return strange result when array doesn't contain null terminator?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have two programs. Both initialize an array from a string literal. In one case the array size is exactly the number of characters I want to place in the array.

I wonder why the output of the size returned by `strlen()` differs for both prorgams. Is it because of the terminating null character is missing? If so, then why is the output 16?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char str[5] = "ankit";
    printf("size of = %d \n ",sizeof(str));
    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("length = %d \n ",len);
}
```

**output :- size of = 5 , length = 16**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char str[] = "ankit";
    printf("size of = %d \n ",sizeof(str));
    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("length = %d \n ",len);
}
```

**output :- size of = 6 , length = 5**

Comment: You need to study C strings and null termination.

Comment: If you keep walking in a straight line, why do you eventually plunge into water?

Comment: If array does not contain null terminator it is not a string. `strlen()` works with strings, so sending such an array to `strlen()` is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: The null terminator tells C where the current string ends. If there is none, your string will go on until you run into a null terminator somewhere else in memory or your program crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first code, by writing

```
 char str[5] = "ankit";
```

you don't have any space left for the null terminator to get stored, which is required to be there for `str` to be used as a *string* . So, in that case, [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by overrunning the allocated memory in search of the null terminator.

OTOH, in the second snippet,

```
char str[] = "ankit";
```

you leave the size allocation to the compiler and it allocates memory for the elements in the string literal used as initializer plus the null terminator. So, you got the desired result.

IMO, always use the later approach, saves a lot of headache from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

Your `char[5]` is too short to hold the values `"ankit"`.

As you say yourself, there is `\0`-termination at the end of a C-style string. That means, your string literal is actually internally represented as `"ankit\0"` (where \0 is a single character).

Since the `strlen()`-function does not find the `\0` character, it's behavior is undefined.

That means, you need a `char[6]` to represent your string.
By omitting the explicit length of the array, you let the compiler choose the size (through the initialization, which is known at compile-time). Therefore, the compiler allocates the correct size (6 chars).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because the array in the first example does not set aside enough space for the 0 terminator.  Here's how `strlen` basically works:

```
size_t strlen( const char *str )
{
  size_t len = 0;
  while( *str++ )
    len++;
  return len;
}
```

`strlen` starts at the *address* of the first element in `str` and "walks" down successive addresses until it sees a `0`-valued byte.  Since `strlen` doesn't know how big the array corresponding to `str` actually is (all it gets is a pointer to the first element), it will keep going past the end of the array until it sees a `0`.

All strings are arrays of `char`, but not all arrays of `char` are strings; if there isn't a zero terminator, it isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

`char str[5]` can at max take 4 chars in it with last extra byte should reserve for '\0' character. Hence its undefined behavior.

Comment: `NULL` and `null` are two different things, isn't it?